# ganglia web frontend isn't working properly in debian lenny

Tags: debian, ganglia

I installed Ganglia gmetad in a Debian Lenny box. But I learned that there is no package installation support for its webfrontend package. So I manually copied some PHP files from elsewhere. The interface is working except graph generation. I tried to find a PHP graphics package used there but so far to no avail. I am wondering if someone has some related experience and a solution on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this manually copying PHP codes from Ubuntu installation to /var/www directory of Debian Lenny machine (after installing apache2 and PHP of course) and then I modified config.php file accordingly.